# How to load pages only on https even an http request

Tags: url, iis, url-rewriting, iis-10

I followed the steps here: https://gridscale.io/en/community/tutorials/iis-redirect-http-to-https-windows/
and everything looks the way it should to me.  If I go to my site with 'https://' the site loads normally, but if I try to go to the site with 'http://' instead of rewriting the url the site does not load.  I confirmed that I am using IIS 10 and it is on Windows Server 2016. How can I make the server load http requests over https?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: article.aspx from that guide does not render.

Comment: What error message did you get? Did you set action="redirect" to "rewrite by mistake? If so when you access http:// you site would fail. The guide just help us know how to troubleshooting URL rewrite with failed request tracing. So no matter the page rendered or not, the rule should always work.

Comment: I get a 404 error after creating the file in the wwwroot directory and navigating to localhost/article.aspx in a browser.  I do not get to the step "Configuring rewrite rules" because the file does not render in the previous step so there is no action to set.

Comment: You don't have to create article.aspx in your application. Its just a sample page show how to use failed request tracing. What you should do is create failed request tracing, enable it. Then reproduce your site not load issue. finally you will find the error log in C:\inetpub\logs\FailedReqLogFiles. Please open it and post error message I asked for.

Comment: hmm no errors but I enabled the failed request tracing and that fixed the problem. http requests are automatically redirected to https requests.  Thanks